# OpenSSL session reuse (Server side) - would like to choose which session to reuse

Tags: openssl

I'm running a basic server, using internal cache (SSL_SESS_CACHE_SERVER cache mode). As so, every time a client sends valid session ID, OpenSSL automatically starts session reuse. I'd like to have an option to decide, based on some very dynamic properties, if I want (or not) to reuse the available session.

If i could get something similar to "SSL_set_session" of client, it would be perfect. OpenSSL will cache the sessions, and i'll decide when and if to use them by using SSL_set_session.

not storing specific sessions is not an option. I'm looking for a way to make the session lookup & reuse - on demand only.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For this, when you first receive the connection (and before the TLS handshake is performed), you could do something like this:

```
int allow_session_reuse = 1;
long sess_cache_mode;

/* Call some code here to determine whether SSL session caching/reuse
 * should be disabled for this connection.
 */
allow_session_reuse = do_session_reuse();

/* Let's assume the answer is "No, we should not allow session reuse
 * for this connection."
 */
if (!allow_session_reuse) {
  long cache_mode;

  /* Disable all session caching on the SSL_CTX object. Note that these
   * session caching modes are for the entire SSL_CTX, not for the
   * individual SSL objects.
   */
  sess_cache_mode = SSL_CTX_set_session_cache_mode(ssl_ctx, SSL_SESS_CACHE_OFF);

} else {
  sess_cache_mode = SSL_CTX_get_session_cache_mode(ssl_ctx);
}

/* .... process your TLS handshake here ... */

/* Make sure to restore the previous session cache mode, for the
 * next connection.
 */
SSL_CTX_set_session_cache_mode(ssl_ctx, sess_cache_mode);
```

If you want more sophisticated handling of cached session data, you would need to look into providing the session caching callbacks using `SSL_CTX_sess_set_get_cb()`.

Hope this helps!